# Notifications ios, 1 always next to icon

Tags: objective-c, ios, notifications

I've recently implemented local notifications but for some reason, I always have a 1 next to the icon of the app regardless of if a notification has triggered or not. Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your Applications badge number to 0 which will remove the badge. You can do this each time your application starts up. This will ensure that the badge is cleared when the user launches your app.

As for the **1** always appearing on your application regardless of notifications, somewhere in your app you have set the badge number to 1. Go through your code thoroughly to check for any indications that you have set the badge number.

### Remove Badge

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{ 
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
}
```

Comment: I see. I'm always setting it to one. Is there a way I can increment that number? I was thinking i could increment a counter but if a notification is set to fire earlier then a previously made notification it's going to display wrong.